# /var/lib/mysql grows indefinitely in size

Tags: mysql, upgrade, size

Having the need to upgrade from Ubuntu Bionic to Ubuntu Focal, I made an upgrade from server 5.7 - deduced afterward - to 8.0 by simply inheriting the original `/var/lib/mysql` directory, that is I left those files where they were (after making a backup of that directory). To get rid of some incompatibility found in the original configuration file (my.cnf) I purged everything from the old package and started the new 8 server with the configuration shipped with its package.

Apparently, the server was working fine, that is I didn't find any particular complaint in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and websites were finding their expected data.

But after a few days, I found the disk space was totally or almost exhausted. I freed some space and noticed `/var/lib/mysql` has grown from about 38G to more than 100G (I issued the command `du -sh *` in `/var/lib`), and was still growing.

What did I do wrong? Perhaps I made a big mistake in upgrading the server in the way I mentioned.

Comment: You _must_ run `mysql_upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. Though upon launching mysql_upgrade I get a response response whose initial part follows - the entire response cannot be reported in a single comment here, it's too long for that. "The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory."

Comment: Oops -- I guess I can't keep up with all the changes.  This change is great.  Alas, this does not answer your Question.  See if you can discover the big files in (or under) that directory.  Perhaps there are a lot of "binlogs"?  Or maybe something else.